# Get the creation date of a tag from the Stack Exchange API

Tags: tags, stackexchange-api

I am querying the SE API, on site Stack Overflow, to get data on the tags used on the site.

The endpoint for [tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) furnishes said tags without the creation date, so that in fact the typical response is (this is the first items, where sorting has been set on popularity)

```
{
  'count': 1303710,
  'has_synonyms': True,
  'is_moderator_only': False,
  'is_required': False,
  'name': u'javascript'
}
```

Now, I'd need the creation date of tags as well, which is data found on the site itself, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), where it says that 'javascript' as a tag has been created 8 years ago as to today.

Because this is the info page of the tag, I'd have thought that the `tags/{tags}/info` endpoint would give me that data. It does not seem to, as I'm getting the same result as above, and you can check it from the UI [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#order=desc&sort=popular&tags=javascript&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Also tried endpoint `tags/{tags}/wiki`, with [no success](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags#tags=javascript&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Any way I can get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the only way to get this data out of the API is to query for the first appeared post with that tag and get its date.